# (libvirt + oVirt) Migrating libvirt server to oVirt

Tags: linux, centos, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, ovirt

I have two centOS 7 servers using the same network. One with libvirt, with some machines connected on it, and another one with oVIRT 4.2. 
I'd like to export the libvirt machines to the oVirst 4.2 server. 
I'm trying to achieve this by pointing the virtual machine's server (libvirt) on oVirt using URI (quemu + ssh://root@10.2.7.32/system), on configurations. 
The problem is that i cannot access the external server.

The error message:

```
Failed to communicate with the external provider, see log for additional details.
```

The log:

VDSM PowerEdge2900 command GetVmsNamesFromExternalProviderVDS failed: Cannot 
   recv data: Could not create directory '/.ssh'.
   Host key verification failed.: Connection reset by peer

What could I do to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The libvirt host's root account must be able to log-in to the oVirt host via passwordless ssh. Use `ssh-copy-id` to set that up.